# Number of each generating elements of the Cayley graph appearing in a Hamiltonian cycle

Tags: graph-theory, finite-groups, hamiltonian-path, cayley-graphs, hamiltonicity

Let $G$ be a finite group and $S$ be a subset of $G$. Let the Cayley graph of $G$ with respect to $S$ be $Cay(G,S)$, provided that $1 {\not\in} S$ and $S$ is inverse closed.

Consider the Cayley graph of a finite group, as an example say, $Cay(\mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_5, \{g_1,g_2\})$, where $g_1=(0,1)$ and $g_2=(1,0)$, $|g_1|=5$, $|g_2|=3$. A rough sketch of the Cayley graph is as follows.

[image: Figure 1]

Some Hamiltonian cycles starting with $(0,0)$ vertex in the Cayley graph are,

1. $g_2^{-1} g_1 g_2 g_1 g_2^{-1} g_1 g_2^{2} g_1^{-4} g_2^2 g_1$, which can be simplified to $g_1^4 g_1^{-4} g_2^{5} g_2^{-2}$
2. $g_1^4 g_2 g_1^{-3} g_2 g_1^4 g_2^{-2}$, which can be simplified to $g_1^8 g_1^{-3} g_2^2 g_2^{-2}$
3. $g_1 g_2 g_1^{-1} g_2 g_1^2 g_2^{-2} g_1 g_2^2 g_1 g_2^{-2} g_1$, which can be simplified to $g_1^6 g_1^{-1} g_2^4 g_2^{-4}$

So, the Hamiltonian cycles are in the form $g_1^{x_1} g_1^{-x_2} g_2^{x_3} g_2^{-x_4}$ for some values $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$.

I observed that,

a) The product of the generating elements in each of the above Hamiltonian cycles became equal to $(0,0)$.

b) $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=15$.

c) $x_1 - x_2 \equiv 0 (mod 5)$ and $x_3 - x_4 \equiv 0 (mod 3)$.

Now, from $a, b, c$ conditions, thinking back about the Hamiltonian cycles, I can get the values $(4,4,5,2), (8,3,2,2), (6,1,4,4)$ as possible solutions for $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)$ respectively (satisfying the $a, b, c$ conditions). But I also get $(3,3,6,3)$ as a possible solution, but I am unable to find a Hamiltonian cycle for such values of $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$ (i.e. generating element $g_1$ is appearing 3 times in the cycle etc. which seems not possible).

Q1: So, there is no cycle having the values $(3,3,6,3)$, am I right? Or have I missed that cycle?

Q2: If there is no such cycle, then it seems like I can not obtain values for $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$ using only $a, b, c$ conditions. Can any suggestion be given to include more conditions so that I can get only the values corresponding to Hamiltonian cycles?

Comment: A brute-force search didn't find such Hamiltonian cycles, but you have also missed other solutions, such as $(7,2,6,0)$. There are several others with zeroes.

Comment: Thank you very much @MishaLavrov after obtaining set of solutions then probably I will have to consider permutations of $g_1^{x_1} g_1^{-x_2} g_2^{x_3} g_2^{-x_4}$ (for the sets of values obtained for $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)$ obtained), and see whether any of the permutation will correspond to a Hamiltonian cycle, right?

Comment: Or any easier method? Thanks a lot in advance. :)